# Dark Sky API Iterate daily through one year in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, api, loops, date, iteration

I just try to get the weather data for a time range.
I want to get daily OR hourly data for a whole year.
I just tried the following code:

```
from forecastiopy import *
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2015, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2015, 12, 31)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    time = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print('DATE: ', time)


city = [40.730610, -73.935242]

fio = ForecastIO.ForecastIO(apikey,
                            units=ForecastIO.ForecastIO.UNITS_SI,
                            lang=ForecastIO.ForecastIO.LANG_ENGLISH,
                            latitude=city[0], longitude=city[1])

print('Latitude:', fio.latitude, 'Longitude:', fio.longitude)
print('Timezone', fio.timezone, 'Offset', fio.offset)
print(fio.get_url()) # You might want to see the request url

if fio.has_hourly() is True:
    hourly = FIOHourly.FIOHourly(fio)
    print('Hourly')
    print('Summary:', hourly.summary)
    print('Icon:', hourly.icon)

for hour in range(0, hourly.hours()):
    print('Hour', hour+1)
    for item in hourly.get_hour(hour).keys():
        print(item + ' : ' + str(hourly.get_hour(hour)[item]))
        # Or access attributes directly for a given minute.
        print(hourly.hour_5_time)
else:
    print('No Hourly data')
```

I get:

```
DATUM:  2015-01-01
DATUM:  2015-01-02
DATUM:  2015-01-03
...
DATUM:  2015-12-29
DATUM:  2015-12-30
Latitude: 40.73061 Longitude: -73.935242
Timezone America/New_York Offset -4
Hourly
Summary: Light rain starting this afternoon.
Icon: rain
Hour 1
visibility : 16.09
humidity : 0.52
...
Hour 49
visibility : 16.09
humidity : 0.57
apparentTemperature : 23.52
icon : partly-cloudy-day
precipProbability : 0
windGust : 2.7
uvIndex : 2
time : 1498395600
precipIntensity : 0
windSpeed : 2.07
pressure : 1014.84
summary : Mostly Cloudy
windBearing : 37
temperature : 23.34
ozone : 308.33
cloudCover : 0.65
dewPoint : 14.43
1498237200
```

How can I use for the time parameter each day of a specific year to get 365 daily reports or 365 * 24 hourly reports? I am not a specialist in python.

Comment: I am in the same boat, I know that you have to include the date in the API call. Using the daily and hourly call as you have above just requests the current date's weather, which automatically calls hours 1 - 49. You will need to find a way to call the API and loop through each day.

Answer (score 1):

This blog provides some code to query between dates https://nipunbatra.github.io/blog/2013/download_weather.html

```
times = []
data = {}
for attr in attributes:
    data[attr] = []

start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
for offset in range(1, 60):
    forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(api_key, lat, lng, time=start+datetime.timedelta(offset), units="us")
    h = forecast.hourly()
    d = h.data
    for p in d:
        times.append(p.time)
        try:
            for i in attributes:
                data[i].append(p.d[i])
        except:
            print(KeyError)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=times)
```

It works for me on python 3.6...however, i am getting a error KeyError: 'temperature' when i query dates around march 2019 for my coordinates... so in this code I added try catach error in the for p in d loop

Hope this helps